# "lsusb" command is not showing the details of all connected devices to usb port

Tags: drivers, lsusb

i am using joystick for my project(desktop application).
to check whether the joystick is connected or not i am using lsusb command.
basically if joystick is connected this command will show the model name of joystick (example "SHANWAN Android Gamepad" and "DragonRise Inc. PC TWIN SHOCK Gamepad" )

when i connect two joystick to system("SHANWAN Android Gamepad" and "DragonRise Inc. PC TWIN SHOCK Gamepad" )
for some systems this command is giving the info about all devices connected like this

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 413c:2113 Dell Computer Corp. Dell KB216 Wired Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 413c:301a Dell Computer Corp. Dell MS116 USB Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 028: ID 2563:0526 **SHANWAN Android Gamepad**
Bus 001 Device 029: ID 0079:0006 **DragonRise Inc. PC TWIN SHOCK Gamepad**
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

and for some system it is showing a blank like this

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 413c:2113 Dell Computer Corp. Dell KB216 Wired Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 413c:301a Dell Computer Corp. Dell MS116 USB Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 028: ID 2563:0526 
Bus 001 Device 029: ID 0079:0006 **DragonRise Inc. PC TWIN SHOCK Gamepad**
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

this above info shows that both joystick are connected but the model name of SHANWAN is not showing. how to solve this?

Comment: Looks like the file of `/lib/udev/hwdb.d/20-usb-vendor-model.hwdb` is missing the lines of `usb:v2563p0526*  ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=Android Gamepad` which should allow for proper identification of the controller.  If the proper drivers are available could be a whole other story.

Answer (score 1):

The command `lsusb` combines the data from the system (/sys/bus/usb/devices) with the hardware database (/lib/udev/hwdb.bin) to produce a human readable output (see `man hwdb`).

Whatever is not found in hwdb can not be displayed.

Seems some of your systems don't have your "SHANWAN Android Gamepad" in the hwdb.